# Converting custom PdfLaTeX command to LuaLaTex for graphics

Tags: pdftex, luatex

I orginally had a PDFlatex engine running which included the following custom command:

```
\newcommand{\allgraphic}[1]{
  \begin{center}
     \pdfximage{#1}%
     \multido{\i=1+1}{\the\pdflastximagepages}{
        \includegraphics[page=\i,width=0.48\textwidth]{#1}
     }
  \end{center} 
}
```

However, I have now moved from PDFLatex to Lualatex and the above command no longer works. I am aware the issue is related to `\pdfximage`, however, how do I get the same result as the above command but with LuaLaTex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pdfximage` is `\saveimageresource` in luatex  and `\pdflastximagepages` is `\lastsavedimageresourcepages`  or add `\usepackage{luatex85}` to define all the old names.

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you.